# Offline map in satellite view iOS sdk

Tags: ios, offline, satellite

Is there any sdk free or paid through which we can download maps for offline usage and use satellite view as map style?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Mapbox(https://www.mapbox.com/), but for offline navigation directions, you have to become an enterprise customer(Purchase Plan).

There you can download the Satellite Map view by using map style.